# Haskell: GHCi Load as much as possible, rather than fail or error

Tags: haskell, ghci

In Haskell using GHCi is there a way to load a file such as the one below, that lets you test the methods that have bindings.

**Use case:** trying to test part of my module, while having skeleton code for the rest of it. (as to not have an XY problem)

```
module X (methodA, methodB, methodC) where

methodA :: String->String
methodA name = "Hello " ++ name

methodB :: Int -> String

methodC :: String -> String
```

This obviously outputs the correct error : `The type signature for ‘methodB’ lacks an accompanying binding`.
For example I would like something similar to below to work.

```
GHCi, version 8.0.1: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Prelude> :l example.hs 
[1 of 1] Compiling X                ( example.hs, interpreted )

example.hs:6:1: error:
    The type signature for ‘methodB’ lacks an accompanying binding

example.hs:8:1: error:
    The type signature for ‘methodC’ lacks an accompanying binding
Failed, modules loaded: none.
Prelude> methodA "jamesmstone"

<interactive>:2:1: error:
    Variable not in scope: methodA :: [Char] -> t
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `-fdefer-type-errors`. This will give you warnings about type errors but won't prevent you from running the other well-typed parts of your program.

Example:

If `Program.hs` contains:

```
foo :: Int
foo = 'a'

main = putStrLn "Hello, world"
```

Then with -fdefer-type-errors you can still load and run `main`:

```
$ ghci -fdefer-type-errors Program.hs
GHCi, version 7.10.2: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( Program.hs, interpreted )

Program.hs:5:7: Warning:
    Couldn't match expected type ‘Int’ with actual type ‘Char’
    In the expression: 'a'
    In an equation for ‘foo’: foo = 'a'
Ok, modules loaded: Main.
*Main> main
Hello, world
*Main>
```

Answer (score 3):

Just give them a binding that doesn't work:

```
methodB = undefined
methodC = undefined
```